# Make Exe Continue Till A Thread Has Completed

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I am compiling my Python script into a Windows Executable. The script simply downloads a a files and saves them locally - each download uses a different thread. I am finding that my simple application exits before any of the threads finish. But I am not entirely sure?

Does my script below exit before the threads finish or does the script wait till they are done? AND If the script does exit before the threads finish - How can I stop this?

Whats they standard practice to avoid this? Should I use a while loop that checks if any threads are still alive or is there a standard way of doing this?

```
import thread
import threading
import urllib2

def download_file():

    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://website.com/file.f")
    print "Res: " + str(response.read())
    raw_input("Press any key to exit...")

def main():

    # create thread and run
    #thread.start_new_thread (run_thread, tuple())

    t = threading.Thread(target=download_file)
    t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    # The below prints before "Res: ..." which makes me think the script exits before the thread has completed
    print("script exit")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the join() function on your newly created thread, which will block the execution of code until the thread is done. I took the liberty of removing your def main() as it is completely not needed here and only creates confusion.
If you want to wrap the launch of all downloads into a neat function, then pick a descriptive name for it.

```
import thread
import threading
import urllib2
def download_file():
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://website.com/file.f")
    print "Res: " + str(response.read())
    raw_input("Press any key to exit...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=download_file)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    # The below prints before "Res: ..." which makes me think the script exits before the thread has completed
    print("script exit")
```

Comment: Thanks this was nicely explained, plus an easy solution for me :D

Comment: @JakeM, I agree with this answer. You can also try `threads = threading.enumerate()` and then check if the threads are alive. I had the opposite situation where we were having hanging processes. I did that check in a case where I was suspecting that there was some thread still executing that was preventing my main process from exiting. I came to understand that if a thread was still doing something then the main process will not end even if it hits exit.